# Change date and data cells in .csv file progressively

Tags: bash, csv, for-loop, awk, sed

I have a file that I'm trying to get ready for my boss in time for his manager's meeting tomorrow morning at 8:00AM -8GMT. I want to retroactively change the dates in non consecutive rows in this .csv file: (truncated)

```
,,,,,
,,,,,sideshow
,,,
date_bob,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
bob_available,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383,531383
bob_used,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312,448312
,,,
date_mel,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
mel_available,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537,343537
mel_used,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159,636159
,,,
date_sideshow-ws2,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
sideshow-ws2_available,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239,936239
sideshow-ws2_used,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441,43441
,,,
,,,,,simpsons
,,,
date_bart,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
bart_available,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559,62559
bart_used,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117,1135117
,,,
date_homer,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
homer_available,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799,17799
homer_used,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877,1179877
,,,
date_lisa,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
lisa_available,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899,3899
lisa_used,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777,1193777
```

In other words a row that now reads:

```
date_lisa,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14,09-17-14
```

would desirably read:

```
date_lisa,09-04-14,09-05-14,09-06-14,09-07-14,09-08-14,09-09-14,09-10-14,09-11-14,09-12-14,09-13-14,09-14-14,09-15-14,09-16-14,09-17-14
```

I'd like to make the daily available numbers less at the beginning and then get progressively bigger day by day. This will mean that the used rows will have to be proportionately smaller at the beginning and then get progressively bigger in lock step with the available rows as they shrink.

Not by a large amount don't make it look obvious just a few GB here and there. I plan to make pivot tables and graphs out of this and so it has to vary a little. BTW the numbers are all in MB as I generated them using df -m.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `awk` does what you need:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
/^date/ {
    split ($2, date, /-/); 
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        $i = date[1] "-" sprintf ("%02d", date[2] - NF + i) "-" date[3]
    }
}
/available|used/ {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        $i = int (($i*i)/NF)
    }
}1' csv
```

- Set the Input and Output Field Separator to `,`
- All the lines that start with date, we split the second column to find the date part.
- We iterate from second column to the end of the line and set the column to new calculated start date which basically uses the current date and the total number of fields.
- All other lines remain as is and gets printed along with modified lines.
- This has a caveat of not rolling over different months correctly.
- For data fields we iterate from second column to the end of line and do a calculation to make them progressively greater than the previous one to match the original value for last field.

Comment: It worked to perfection, that saved me quite a bit of time and I doubt I ever would have come up with something so complex. Can you do the second half of my question with the data rows? If not it's okay thanks for everything.

Comment: @BrianBills Please check the updated version. I made some corrections.

Comment: Amazing the updated solution is incredible. I don't know how to thank you enough I'm trying to go from contractor to FTE and this opportunity is my big break. You just swooped in here, waved your magic wand, and voila amazing. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @BrianBills I did make one more change to the solution and I am glad it worked out for you. I would however recommend reading [GNU awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to allow you make a lasting impression. For anything else, we are here to help. Good luck at work!! `:)`

Comment: Thanks I will read that manual. I think awk is the coolest, every solution I've gotten so far has employed a healthy dose of it.